# service worker install event is called before register event is completed

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have attached install event to service worker as below. But Install event fired before register event is completed. See code snippets and console logs below.

My concern is how install event is fired before register event is completed?

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js',{scope : '/'}).then(function(registration) {
    // Registration was successful
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // registration failed :(
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
  });
}


var cacheName = 'V-1';
var filesToCache = [
  '/', '/index.html',
  '/css/all.css', '/css/material.min.css',
  '/js/all.js', '/js/material.min.js',
  '/images/service-worker-1.png','/images/service-worker-2.png','/images/service-worker-3.png',
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Installing');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache
              .addAll(filesToCache) //this is atomic in nature i.e. if any of the file fails the entire cache step fails.
              .then(() => {console.log('[ServiceWorker] App shell Caching  Successful');})
              .catch(() => {console.log('[ServiceWorker] App shell Caching  Failed');})
    })
  );
});
```

[image: Console Logs]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @abraham I have updated the description. How install event is fired before register event gets completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`navigator.serviceWorker.register()` is not an event. It's a function that returns a promise, and then promise will resolve with a [`ServiceWorkerRegistration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration) object that corresponds to the registration.

The actual service worker logic is executed in a different thread/process, and the lifecycle events that the service worker handles, like the `install` event, happen independently of the web page that registered the service worker. What you're seeing in your `console.log()` output is expected.

If you want to keep track of the state of the service worker from your web page, you can add event listeners to the `ServiceWorkerRegistration` object. There's an example of this at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/registration-events/index.html

If you want to write code that will cause your web page to wait until there's an active service worker before it takes some action, you could make use of the [`navigator.serviceWorker.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/ready) promise.

Comment: could you explain little bit elaborately how come service worker install event is fired even before registration gets completed? I am getting confused here.

Comment: Think of the process of registration as a web page telling the browser "this is the location of my service worker JavaScript". As soon as the browser knows where to fetch the JS from, registration is complete. The process of actually downloading and executing the SW's code happens after registration. The promise returned by `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` resolves at some point after the SW code has started executing, but since we're talking about asynchronous, multithreaded code here, the exact timing can be hard to pin down.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations :)