# Cannot install service worker in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to use service workers in Chrome on **localhost:3000**.
My app is using AngularJS 1.5.

The service worker state is not activating. It is going from **installing** to **redundant**.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('/service-worker.js')
    .then(function(registration) {
        var serviceWorker;
        if (registration.installing) {
            serviceWorker = registration.installing;
        } else if (registration.waiting) {
            serviceWorker = registration.waiting;
        } else if (registration.active) {
            serviceWorker = registration.active;
        }

        if (serviceWorker) {
            console.log("ServiceWorker phase:", serviceWorker.state);

            serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', function (e) {
                console.log("ServiceWorker phase:", e.target.state);
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Service Worker Error', err);
    });
}
```

*Output of above script:*

> ServiceWorker phase: installing
>
> ServiceWorker phase: redundant

`service-worker.js` is available at http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js. I don't see any error messages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If sw become redundant, there is an error in the sw no in the registry. If you show you sw code, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Try close all the tabs of you webpage. Service Workers will be reinstall only if there is no active tab is using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [service worker install event is called before register event is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902060/service-worker-install-event-is-called-before-register-event-is-completed)

Comment: facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and this is how I fixed it:

- Browse the page, which has the service worker running
- Navigate to `chrome://inspect/#service-workers` in chrome browser
- Find your service worker, which is in redundant state and click terminate

[image: terminate the SW]

- Refresh your page which has the service worker
- Open developer console, go to the application tab and then service worker section. you should see the green icon with your service worker now.
- Add following function in your SW

  `self.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
  });`

[image: verify the working SW]